# Foursquare venues/search API retrieve far fewer results than 2 months ago

Tags: api, foursquare

I noticed that my Foursquare API queries (in particular venues/search) retrieve far fewer results than 2 months ago.
I have already checked the [Foursquare API changelog](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog), but the last update was on 08/gen/16.

Anyone know what happened on Foursquare venues/search API? Thanks in advance.

There it is an example of what I mean, with a bounded box query (the same thing happens with a lot of other bounded box queries):

----- Query -----

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?limit=50&intent=browse&sw=45.45100954050204,9.186157156018526&ne=45.451907855263556,9.187437694511546&v=20160422&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET

----- Results on 25/04/2016 -----

[1] 4c990a50d799a1cd547bb752

[2] 5676fdf4498e9399a82c01ba

[3] 56473d03498efa22f4d64ad2

[4] 56066aaf498e96c1a237d7e7

[5] 4d8dc80f6174a093c9feb7e3

[6] 51ee8b34498eec9f7706d4eb

[7] 4f324a58e4b010a3c1062aaa

[8] 519cfa06498e593e75cf78b2

[9] 4d5961bed0332c0f28c068da

[10] 4f613abbe4b0deb11b25c080

[11] 4d904ad1cb9b224b5db4ac41

[12] 4d6d48c1a6ff721e6aeac120

[13] 4e6a475245ddadf2d065cee5

[14] 4c10f316ce640f472cb13a52

[15] 51233bffe4b097759a54e7c7

[16] 4c0d0fbd7189c9280563d6b6

[17] 4e3d263ee4cdab9b933ecb53

[18] 559ae67f498e09fb3963be03

[19] 4d78d96e930ef04d2ad7bc4f

[20] 4f4e6e85e4b0577d81ef1580

[21] 5112565be4b0946f57672991

[22] 4fc49ab07716edd7c39eda13

[23] 50ea7bc7e4b04975531421db

[24] 4bc0a038920eb7137430192c

[25] 4d88d777401a224bf2798018

[26] 4c17911030d30f4759ae36a9

[27] 55bbd056498e5996dd73478b

[28] 4e0e1c32d164fff335a808b7

[29] 4dde341e183877913997991e

[30] 54293d23498e4908f3426159

[31] 5045ceaee4b00cac6f489132

[32] 4c0d11ab7189c9286366d6b6

[33] 4f8ff584e4b094de9b4ae4ae

[34] 529843f711d2d434953129e9

[35] 4c7cbeed247cb60c13eb5e5e

[36] 4e785651e4cd130429e722f4

[37] 4b058878f964a5209ac722e3

[38] 4f91558ce4b023d6c6e8cd23

[39] 535274a7498e07ed75a756d3

[40] 4e246315b0fbdf9ba7c6caca

----- Results on 21/06/2016 -----

[1] 4c990a50d799a1cd547bb752

[2] 54293d23498e4908f3426159

[3] 4e3d263ee4cdab9b933ecb53

[4] 4d8dc80f6174a093c9feb7e3

[5] 56066aaf498e96c1a237d7e7

[6] 55bbd056498e5996dd73478b

[7] 4f91558ce4b023d6c6e8cd23

[8] 4f8ff584e4b094de9b4ae4ae

[9] 56473d03498efa22f4d64ad2

[10] 4e6a475245ddadf2d065cee5

[11] 4e0e1c32d164fff335a808b7

[12] 535274a7498e07ed75a756d3

[13] 4f613abbe4b0deb11b25c080

[14] 4c10f316ce640f472cb13a52

[15] 4e7542cfe4cd3254373e9652

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This is a bug in the "limit" parameter of venues/search API. In particular, the number of returned results doesn't match the "limit" param in the request, as you can see -for example- in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWp2g.jpg) containing 50 values (1, 2, ..., 50) of the limit parameter and the relative numbers of returned results for the aforementioned query.

Unfortunately, it seems that the Foursquare API team has not yet fixed this issue.